# How to add space between digits of number?

Tags: vue.js

I have got input field where user can type: `10000`, but I want to make it's displayed as `10 000`. How it's possible to do it with vue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create custom filter that splits your number by 3 digits from end ( if there are more than 3 digits ) using regular expression, and add it to your app:

```
Vue.filter('splitNumber', function (value) {
   return value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ");
})
```

Then just use it as filter:

```
<span v-text="yourNumber | splitNumber"></span>
```